# Checkbox problems with meteor template and blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor-blaze

I have some code that was working happily pre-blaze that is now not working as expected post blaze and the changes to checkbox handling.

The code is pretty simple

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <label for="packed" class="checkbox-inline input-lg">Packed</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="packed" id="packed" checked={{isPacked evt}}/>
    {{#if isPacked evt}}
      Packed
    {{else}}
      Not Packed
    {{/if}}
    <label for="delivered" class="checkbox-inline input-lg">Delivered</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delivered" id="delivered" disabled={{disDelivered evt}}  checked={{isDelivered evt}}/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="closeEdit">Close</button>
  </div>
```

The line "Not Packed" is displayed as expected, but, the check boxes are both checked (although both tests return false) and delivered is, as expected disabled.

I can't for the life of me work out why the check boxes are now checked even though the test returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blaze will automatically turn returned object into attributes so you could return `{checked:"checked"}` from isPacked when the checkbox should be checked or return implicitly when it should not be.

Comment: I just tried returning `{checked:"checked"}`and it didn't work until I also changed the html to:
`<input type="checkbox" name="packed" id="packed" {{isPacked evt}}/>`
This worked just fine. Thanks @Kelly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that working with any recent release of Meteor as it results in an error. Check this out for more details: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

Comment: This still works perfectly in 0.9.4 as can be seen in this meteorpad: http://meteorpad.com/pad/zyTWugodWr8vBbSnu